# Password value magically disappears on form submit

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set up frontend authentication for a react application running on a Django REST-API.

The registration API endpoint works well if I send the request on Postman. However, the program is behaving very odd when I type information into my frontend registration form and click on submit.

Please look at the code below - I use a `useInputState` hook to keep track of the state of a given input. This works fine.

The `registerUser` function takes in username, password and email and sends a Post-Request to the dedicated API Endpoint.

The `handleSubmit` function checks if the passwords match and throws an error if they don't this works fine as well. If the passwords do match, it calls `registerUser` and provides the users input.

Now somewhere along the way, the password that has been passed into `registerUser` disappears (see comments). I have no idea where this issue could come from and any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function Register() {
  const { auth, dispatchAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { dispatchErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
  const { dispatchMessages } = useContext(MessageContext);

  const [username, setUsername] = useInputState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useInputState("");
  const [password1, setPassword1] = useInputState("");
  const [password2, setPassword2] = useInputState("");

  const registerUser = ({ username, password, email }) => {
    // headers
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    // Request body
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      username,
      password,
      email,
    });
    console.log("body:");
    console.log(body);
    // Output looks like: {"username":"testuser","email":"email@test.com"}
    // Where did the password go?!

    axios
      .post("/api/auth/register/", body, config)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatchAuth({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatchErrors(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
        dispatchAuth({ type: REGISTER_FAIL });
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password1 !== password2) {
      dispatchMessages(
        createMessage({ passwordsNotMatch: "Passwords do not match" })
      );
    } else {
      console.log(password1); // Console output still contains the password
      const newUser = { username, password1, email };
      registerUser(newUser);
    }
  };
```

EDIT: Okay I'm an idiot and didn't notice that I need to change `const newUser = { username, password1, email };` to be `const newUser = { username, password, email };`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm an idiot and didn't notice that I need to change `const newUser = { username, password1, email };` to be const `newUser = { username, password, email };`